# Eclipse Java project can't run with some strange errors

Tags: java

Hi all I am getting the following errors when I've tried to run an open source project, any idea to avoid these errors,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import net cannot be resolved
    The import net cannot be resolved
    The import net cannot be resolved
    PacketSource cannot be resolved to a type
    PacketSource cannot be resolved to a type
    BuildSource cannot be resolved
    PacketSource cannot be resolved to a type
    PacketSource cannot be resolved to a type
    PrintStreamMessenger cannot be resolved to a variable
    PacketSource cannot be resolved to a type
    PacketSource cannot be resolved to a type
    PacketSource cannot be resolved to a type
    PrintStreamMessenger cannot be resolved to a variable
    PacketSource cannot be resolved to a type

    at Classes.snifferImpl.<init>(snifferImpl.java:32)
    at Classes.Zmonitor$1$1.run(Zmonitor.java:86)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: put required jars in class path

Comment: Can you add your code here? Unless how can we help you? Only log can't give more information. It seems you are missing import jar.

Comment: Bottom panel-> java problems.

Comment: rebuild the project...

Comment: Go to project>build. Then make sure there are no little red X's in your code. These are compilation errors. If the X's have a lightbulb next to them, then you can click it for auto fix options.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unresolved compilation problems
```

Means two things can go wrong in Eclipse:

1) Your src folder is not marked as source folder

> Go to Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Source and add the source
>   folder

2) You have some jar files referenced from your project which either is not present in the project or is not in you classpath.

> Go to Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries and add the jar
>   files (in case you have the jars)

Comment: Many Thanks I've added them as you said but it seems not solved yet can you see the screen shot please. http://postimg.org/image/vc15wlubx/

Comment: I dont see any new post

Comment: sorry see the links http://postimg.org/image/arlyo6r4n/ and http://postimg.org/image/vc15wlubx/919cab8a/

Comment: Sorry buddy... these links are blocked here. Maybe you can post the image in your original post above...